# Change actions sheet's button size?

Tags: iphone

can we change button size of actionsheet, say i hv 4 buttons in actionsheet, than it will cover more than half screen with sheet, is there any other way to giv more than 3 buttons without capturing most of the screen?

regards

Answer (score 0):

The API for UIActionSheet does not provide a way of adding your own custom UIButtons.  Instead, you might want to look at creating your own custom version UIActionSheet - from scratch.  It would be a pretty simple custom UIVIewController with a series of buttons (sized to your liking) and the presentation and dismissal would require a simple animation to slide in and out of view.

Comment: thanks .....do u hv any resource, from where i can create a slide in slide out view, like actionsheet?